# Не сохраняется содержимое массива, при добавлении в вектор C++

Tags: c++, строки, вектор, global-variables

У меня есть функция которая добавляет массив wchar_t в глобальный вектор  vector. Но при выходе из функции добавленное значение меняется на "мусор".

```
vector<wchar_t*> vectorValues;

void function()
{
    wchar_t* pwszItem1 = L"А";
    wstring wsItem1(pwszItem1);

    wchar_t* pwszItem2 = L"Б";
    wstring wsItem2(pwszItem2);

    wchar_t* pwszItem3 = L"В";
    wstring wsItem3(pwszItem3);

    wstring wsItems;
    wsItems += wsItem1;
    wsItems += wsItem2;
    wsItems += wsItem3;

    vectorValues.push_back(const_cast<wchar_t*>(wsItems.c_str()));
}
```

Comment: Еще бы. При выходе из функции локальная переменная `wsItems;` убивается, и, понятно, что указатель на ее внутренний буфер после этого указывает не пойми куда... Почему вы вам не использовать `vector<wstring>`?

Comment: Мне потом все равно нужно будет конвертировать в wchar_t*. Но спасибо за ответ, помогло. Я сделал так и все норм: wstring* wsString = new wstring();

Comment: Или лучше сначала сохранить в wstring, а потом перевести в wchar_t*?

Comment: @ivan pupkin: Никакого "все норм" так не получится: ваши объекты теперь стали утечками памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `wsItems`, объявленная в функции как

```
wstring wsItems;
```

является локальной переменной этой функции, а, следовательно, по завершению работы функции она перестает существовать. В результате указатель, возвращаемый функцией-членом класса `c_str` становится не действительным за пределами функции.

Вам следует либо использовать вектор типа `std::vector<std::wstring>`, либо каждый раз динамически выделять память для очередной строки, переписывать туда строку и указатель заносить в вектор. В этом случае вам следует не забывать освобождать память под выделенную строку, когда какой-то элемент из вектора удаляется. То есть второе решение является не эффективным по сравнению с первым решением.